# nginx and two certificates for one domain (EV nad wildcard)

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, spdy, sni

we have for our domain.tld two certificates. One with EV (for domain.tld and www.domain.tld) and wildcard for subdomains.

Our website is running on www.domain.tld (always) and subdomains are used for images (img.domain.tld).

We are using nginx "virtual hosts":

```html
  server {
#        listen       443;
        listen       443 ssl spdy;
        server_name  domain.tld *.domain.tld;
      
        ssl on;
        
        # wildcard        
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/cert/wildcard/uni_STAR_domain_tld.crt;                               
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/cert/wildcard/wildcarddomain.tld.key;
...
```

```html
  server {
#        listen       443;
        listen       443 ssl spdy;
        server_name  www.domain.tld;
      
        ssl on;
        
        # EV        
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/cert/wildcard/EV_cert_domain_tld.crt;                               
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/cert/wildcard/EV.cert.domain.tld.key;
...
```

**Problem is that sometimes is for www.domain.tld used EV certificate and sometimes wildcard certificate. Why?**

We are running on single dedicated IP address, but nginx has SNI support enabled.

Comment: Which of those configs is included first?

Comment: I tried switch them. There is no difference. Sometimes is website on EV and sometimes on wildcard. It is changing in one session on site.

Comment: Just an idea : maybe it's spdy : when you connect to domain.tld, your browser open a tls session. When you connect to www.domain.tld, the ip is the same, the certificate you had for domain.tld IS valid for that request, to maybe spdy just decide to reuse the previous tls session.

Comment: See https://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper :  "In many cases, SPDY can stream all requests over a single connection, regardless of the number of different domains from which requested resources originate."

Comment: Good idea! Can help change IP for www.domain.tld, domain.tld (IP A for this) AND *.domain.tld (IP B for rest)?

Answer (score 0):

When you think the wildcard show up in www.domain.tld (instead of the EV) can you check the details of the certificate ? Maybe it's the EV :

Due to mixed content, the browser can decide to not show the EV green bar.

https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/932768

https://www.w3.org/TR/mixed-content/

Comment: I checked detail of certificate ... it is not EV :(